# why is django form.errors displayed as string?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using a django form.I pass the form errors to template as,

```
return render_to_response(template_name, {'form':form})
```

In template i need to convert this to a js dictionary so i used,

```
eval({{form.errors|safe}})
```

but wherever i use form.errors in template i get the html format and not the dictionary. why is django forms getting displayed as a string rather than a dictionary. is there a way to  use the dictionary version of form.errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's getting displayed as an unordered list because the [error collection's](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/util.py#L45) `ErrorDict.__unicode__` 
 method returns the value of `ErrorDict.as_ul`.

If you want to get back the default string representation of the dictionary, cast it back to a dictionary: `dict(form.errors)`. Now you won't be getting an HTML formatted unordered list anymore.

#### Update

If your trying to represent a Python dictionary in JS, then keep it simple and encode the dictionary object to JSON. So somewhere in your view:

```
from django.utils import simplejson

errors = simplejson.dumps(form.errors)
```

Comment: The problem with this method is that all the values in the dict are unicode string imean they are prefixed with u'string'.This causes JS errors

Comment: Is there a way to convert them to strings in the dictionary.now i have written a list comprehension to do this.

Comment: Right, after having my morning coffee I've updated the answer with how to get a valid JS representation for the error collection.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at django's source, errors should be of the type django.forms.util.ErrorDict.

Which has the following two methods that might be interesting for your case: as_text and as_ul.

I don't see how you could have used the `eval` method from within a django template. As far as I know that not even a valid standard django template tag.

I think you should manually loop over the dict and print/generate the javascript object literal accordingly.

Comment: you have misunderstood the question . eval() method belongs to JS and is not a template tag